# How do I convert a db3 file (Palm Pre database) to a MySQL file?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, palm

I've copied the db3 database file on my Palm Pre to my computer and would like to convert it to a MySQL database (so I can print the memos). (Or, better, I'd like to find a GUI like PHPMyAdmin that can read the db3 file.)

How can I access that data on a PC best?

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to export the db3 data as a comma seperated list, that then can be imported to MySQL.

Also MS Access can import db3 files. Then you can get it to MySQL through ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

There is [a Firefox plugin that can read SQLlite files](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) (which the Palm db3 file is).

Alternative solutions welcome, especially one which can be turned into a full-script that roots to a plugged-in Palm Pre, downloads a copy of the db3 file, and imports/updates a local database (to create a Palm Pre Desktop (which is lacking)).